# How to add data from junction table to many to many field with DRF serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models like the following and I need to serialize the magazine model with the DjangoRestFramework serializer:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class MagazinePublication(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, ...)
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, ...)

    publication_date = models.DateField(...)

class Magazine(models.Model):
    ...
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication,
                                          through=MagazinePublication)
```

I want to serialize a magazine instance like this so that publications contain their publication dates from the junction (through) table:

```
magazine = {
    id: ...,
    publications = [
        {title: ..., publication_date: ...}
        # here title should come from Publication
        # but publication_date from PublicationMagazine (through model)
        # how to do it?
    ]
}
```

is there a way to do this with DjangoRestFramework serializer? A link to the docs would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can specify inside `Through` model related_name for reverse relation like this:

```
class MagazinePublication(models.Model):
   publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='publication_magazines')
   magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='magazine_publizations')
   publication_date = models.DateField()
```

Now you can use this name inside serializer.

To implement nested serialization you need to add MagazinePublicationSerializer:

```
class MagazinePublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='publication.id')
    title = serializers.IntegerField(source='publication.title')
    class Meta:
       model = MagazinePublication

       fields = ('id', 'title', 'publication_date',)
```

And use this as for publications field inside MagazineSerializer:

```
class MagazineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publications = MagazinePublicationSerializer(source='magazine_publizations', many=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Magazine
       fields = ('id', 'publications',)
```

Chack more details about nested serialization [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: should it be `MagazinePublicationSerializer` instead of `MembershipSerializer`?

Comment: @Bob yes sure:)

Comment: hm but won't publications in MagazineSerializer contain only data from the through table? I must have been unclear in the question, updated it a bit to clarify

Comment: @BobI've updated answer. You can use source to specify field from publication model.